# recaptcha error hashed_account_id is deprecated

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to call Recaptcha Enterprise and it keeps giving me the following error
hashed_account_id is deprecated in (google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/src/V1/Event.php)
and I have the following code to call it

```
 public function createAssessment(string $token, string $platform, string $ID = ''): Assessment
    {
        $siteKey = $this->determineSiteKey($platform);
        $projectName = $this->client->projectName($this->settings->project);
        $userInfo = new UserInfo(); // Assuming UserInfo is the correct class name
        $userInfo->setAccountId($ID); // Set the account_id on the UserInfo object

        $event = (new Event())->setSiteKey($siteKey)->setToken($token)->setUserInfo($userInfo);

        $assessment = (new Assessment())->setEvent($event);
        try {
            $assessment = $this->client->createAssessment($projectName, $assessment);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $assessment;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the appropriate site key based on the platform.
     *
     * @param string $platform The platform (e.g., iOS, Android).
     * @return string The site key for the platform.
     */
    private function determineSiteKey(string $platform): string
    {
        return $platform === 'IOS' ? $this->settings->siteKey_IOS : $this->settings->siteKey_android;
    }
```

Comment: It's probably whatever's calling `createAssessment` is passing a hashed ID